# Help reading an Ellis island record

Tags: palaeography, manifest, images, data-derivation

I wonder if you could help me figure out some text in an Ellis Island record (Line 15).

Here's what I've been able to get so far.  I've put questions marks where I'm not sure.

```
Luka Cacic
Age 23
Occupation: Farm Laborer (?)
Nationality: Hungary
Race (col.9): ?
Last Residence: Lindenharst(?), Germany
Relative: Kata Cacic, Mother  Aleksiner(?) Pazariste Croatia
Destination: Kensington, MD(?)
Passage paid by: Cousin
Who Going to See: Karlo Cacic, Kansas City, Box 106  Sugar Creek ???? City
```

Thank you!

[image: Manifest Page 1] [image: Manifest Page 2]

Comment: I have a terrible time myself trying to read the ship manifest even when I enlarge it.
I've tried cutting and pasting to my docs but it is still hard to read. My guess on the best way is to purchase the manifest from Ellis Island Foundation. Make sure you get the page (s) you need.

Comment: Are the purchased images of much higher resolution and quality? I was assuming it would be about the same but if that's the case it might be worth it.

Answer (score 8):

- Occupation: Farm Laborer (?) (**Yes, farmlab.)**
- Race (col.9): ?
  **Servian** *(Could mean Serbian.)*
- Last Residence: Lindenharst(?) **Lindenhorst** *(A quick search of Google maps found Lindenhorst, Dortmund - Lindenhorst, Helmstedt - Lindenhorst Nauen)*, Germany
- Relative: Mother, Kata Cacic, Aleksiner(?) (**yes, I see Aleksiner/
  could be Aleksimer)** Pazariste Croatia
- Destination: Kensington,
  MD(?) **MO** *(Missouri - you can see the same MO before "box" in
  column 18, which is the same state as Kansas City.)*
- Who Going to See: Karlo Cacic, Kansas City, Box 106 
  Sugar Creek **Crescent** *(FYI, there is an area called Sugar Creek just
  north east of Kansas City.)* ???? City

Answer (score 2):

Some information I have helps add weight to your translation and that of @CanadianGirlScout:

- Luka Cacic and  Karlo Cacic, lived outside Kansas City, MO in Sugar Creek.
- My Grandmother Manda Suknaic came to USA in 1913 and to Sugar Creek, MO to live with a brother-in-law.
- According to my Grandmother's birth certificate Her mother Mara Cacic and Father Steophan Suknaic lived in Aleksinica, Petusic where Manda was born.

Comment: Hello @Skyeking, welcome to G&FH.SE!  Stack Exchange has a question-and-answer format which is a bit different from other websites, so don't be alarmed if your answer is turned into a comment on the original question.  Feel free to explore the site and see if you can answer any of our other questions or if other Q/As can help you. You can learn more about how Stack Exchange works by taking our [tour](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/tour) and visiting the [help center](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help) by clicking 'help' on the top navigation bar.

Comment: If you'd like to turn your post into an answer to the question, you could add some information about Sugar Creek, Missouri and about Aleksinica, and others in the community who may have traveled from one city to the other.  Any links to local resources would be very useful.